# Posting html form values to python script without CGI

Tags: python, html, forms

I intend to write a Python script which receives some form data. I think an HTML form is simple and good enough for my needs. However, I have not found a way to feed the HTML form values to the Python script. I do not want to use CGI as I want to avoid the use of a web sever. The HTML form is intended to be a front end for the Python script. Surely,there is a way to do this without CGI and a web server!

Answer (score 0):

For creating the form, you can use the tkinter python module for graphic interface. It is fairly easy to create a page with different inputs that you can let your user fill in. The information will be provided as raw input rather than HTML form, but then you can use those entries directly in your following python script. https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

If you do want to go through an HTML form, you can then use the python module html.parser (ref. https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

From the documentation, I think you can easily find your way through parsing your input files.

Comment: This will only parse an HTML form that contains data. How do I get the data in the first place?

Comment: So you want to make a python script that writes an HTML document, so that later you can read this HTML document to run another script, it that it ?

Comment: The HTML form should take user input and sends it to Python Script. An HTML parser does not do that.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input ?  Is there a lot of information you need to collect ? otherwise, the good old "raw_input()" with some tests behind should do for your input

Comment: It will be some text field and check boxes. The usual HTML inputs.

Comment: tkinter then to create forms (or even a whole user interface) directly in python